# Send tez to an address, not a contract?

Tags: tezos-client, transactions, transfer, address, compile

I have created a payment function, the problem is that the tez is debited from my contract and I would like it to be debited from a wallet address, how do I do this? If I replace Tezos.transaction unit purchase_price ship_address it gives me a compilation error...

```
let purchase (item,purchase_price, store : nat * tez * nft_token_storage) : operation list * nft_token_storage = 
    let ship_address : address = ("tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" : address) in
    let vendor_address : address = ("tz1M6BCKeb1hWX7DD8qcKB4T5zJKNpsk5YCc" : address) in

    let vendor_contract : unit contract =
      match (Tezos.get_contract_opt (vendor_address) : unit contract option) with
        Some contract -> contract
      | None -> (failwith "Contract not found." : unit contract) in
       let op : operation = Tezos.transaction unit purchase_price vendor_contract in

    if Tezos.source <> ship_address then (failwith ("Access denied"): operation list * nft_token_storage) else
    if Tezos.amount > purchase_price then (failwith ("Incorrect amount"): operation list * nft_token_storage) else ([op], store)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enforce the sender to send an amount equal to `purchase_price`.

```
if Tezos.amount <> purchase_price then failwith ...
```

And when calling the contract you need to provide an `amount` equal to `purchase_price` in the transaction.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, so I have to pass it as a purchase price and amount parameter to my function? because when calling it fails.. it always returns me amount invalid :(

Comment: The initial transaction operation needs to include the respective amount. The transaction has an "amount" field.